# How do I return average processing time for the last x months, for logs only run in past 24 hours

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, average

I have a table that contains logs of processing times. I've added an Elapsed column which return the seconds based on start and end time. The rows returned are for the jobs run in the last 24 hours. I also want to add a column that shows the avg processing time for the last 3 months, and then the difference between todays and the 3 month average.

```
SELECT Job
      ,RunDate
      ,Start
      ,End
      ,DATEDIFF(second,start,end) 'Elapsed(s)'
  FROM table.jobs
  where RunDate between DATEADD (HOUR,-24,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
  order by Job
```

My query returns this:

```
Job     RunDate     Start     End         Elapsed(s)
----------------------------------------------------------
1       2019/06/05  00:12:23  00:13:50    87
2       2019/06/05  00:15:23  00:17:50    147
3       2019/06/05  00:12:00  00:13:50    110
4       2019/06/05  00:10:23  00:11:23    60
5       2019/06/05  01:34:10  01:50:49    999
```

What I would like it to return is:

```
Job     RunDate     Start     End         Elapsed(s)     3monthAVG     Diff
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1       2019/06/05  00:12:23  00:13:50    87             90            3
2       2019/06/05  00:15:23  00:17:50    147            140           -7
3       2019/06/05  00:12:00  00:13:50    110            120           10
4       2019/06/05  00:10:23  00:11:23    60             55            -5
5       2019/06/05  01:34:10  01:50:49    999            1012          13
```

Answer (score 1):

You can precalculate this `average` using a `CTE`. Be a aware of jobs that failed, that can screw your `average`.

```
 with last3months as (
  SELECT Job
      ,avg(DATEDIFF(second,start,end)) as ThreeMonthAverage
  FROM table.jobs
  where RunDate between DATEADD (MONTH,-3,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
  group by Job
)
 SELECT j.Job
      ,j.RunDate
      ,j.Start
      ,j.End
      ,DATEDIFF(second,j.start,j.end) 'Elapsed(s)'
      ,l3.ThreeMonthAverage
      ,l3.ThreeMonthAverage - DATEDIFF(second,j.start,j.end) as Diff
  FROM table.jobs as j
  join last3months as l3
    on l3.job = j.job
  where RunDate between DATEADD (HOUR,-24,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
  order by Job
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. Will the diff be a difference between last3months.ThreeMonthAverage and Elapsed(s) ?

Comment: @graham That's right, it is a subtraction of averages (average time for last 3 months - Elapsed(s)).

Comment: @graham my pleasure.

Comment: Hi. Sorry, me again. I used your solution and it worked! However, my example wasn’t detailed enough. There are several products that run each job, and the processing time differs between products. When I run the query, the average for last 3 months column gave me an average just for that job, and not specifically for that product, as expected. I added product in to the cte, and then added it to the group by but that return a lot more result then expected and incorrect. Any idea?